# Bootstrap column doesn't show properly

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

I want to create a row and 3 columns in that row. This is my code and the column doesn't work properly. It shows as row.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class='row'>
    <div class=' col-md-4'>
     <p><small>Abc</small></p>
     <p class='font-weight-bold'>Example</p>
    </div>
    <div class=' col-md-4'>
     <p><small>Xyz</small></p>
     <p class=' font-weight-bold'>New York</p>
    </div>
    
    <div class=' col-md-4'>
     <a class=' btn btn-primary' style='margin-top: 15px;' role='button'>button</a> 
    </div>
 </div>  
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap 3 or 4?

Comment: Your code is working fine for me.
How you are saving, I mean with what file extension ?

Comment: If I remember correctly: a `class="row"` goes inside an element with `class="container"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is correct! I just changed the Bootstrap version that you have been used to see 'col-4' style and see this works perfectly!

I guess maybe the screen that you are working with, is below '575px' resolution . this causes the responsive style.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 
</head>
<body>

<div class='row'>
    <div class='col-4'>
     <p><small>Abc</small></p>
     <p class='font-weight-bold'>Example</p>
    </div>
    <div class='col-4'>
     <p><small>Xyz</small></p>
     <p class=' font-weight-bold'>New York</p>
    </div>
    
    <div class='col-4'>
     <a class='btn btn-primary' style='margin-top: 15px;' role='button'>button</a> 
    </div>
 </div> 
 
 
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

It works fine, actually, but you are setting your columns to respect only in a screen of medium size or larger.

col-**md**-4

If that was not your intention, you can either:

1. reduce the screen size you are working with: col-**sm**-4 (small), col-**xs**-4 (extra-small)
2. Or scrap the sizing and make your columns respect whatever screen size: col-4

More info on [Bootstrap's grid system](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/)